# Account isn't being created in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

**The issue I have is that the data I get always seems to be when I try to create an account**

> Username must be between 3 and 15 characters

**and the account is never created.**

The thing that also confuses me is that the page gets reloaded to login.html

Create.html Form

```
<form action="create.php" method="post" id="createForm">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
                <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <strong id="strongText" style="display: none;"></strong>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="3u">
                <input type="button" value="Create Account" id="create"/>
            </div>
            <div class ="6u"></div>
            <div class="3u">
                <input type="button" value="Have an account?" id="login"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Create.html javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#create").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("create").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = "Creating account, please wait...<br>";
    $("#strongText").fadeIn();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      },
      url: 'createCheck.php',
      success: function(data) { //Receives the data from the php code 
        //console.log(data);
        if (data == "Unavailable") {
          document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = "Username Unavailable<br>";
          document.getElementById("create").disabled = false;
        } else if (data == 'Username must be between 3 and 15 characters') {
          document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = data + "<br>";
          document.getElementById("create").disabled = false;
        } else if (data == 'Password must be between 5 and 25 characters') {
          document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = data + "<br>";
          document.getElementById("create").disabled = false;
        } else {
          $.post(
            'create.php',
            $('#createform').serialize(),
            function(data, status) {
              document.getElementById('strongText').innerHTML = data + "<br>";
              window.location.href = "login.html";
            }
          );
          //window.location.href = "/login.php";
        }

      },
      error: function(xhr, err) {
        console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });

  });


});
```

createCheck.php

```js
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', "XXX");
define('DB_USER', "XXX");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "XXX");
define('DB_DATABASE', "XXX");

$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed. Please send an email to XXX@XXX.com regarding this problem.";
    exit();
}

if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 15) {
 echo "Username must be between 3 and 15 characters";
} elseif (strlen($password) < 5 || strlen($password) > 25) {
 echo "Password must be between 5 and 25 characters";
} elseif ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `accounts` WHERE username = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    if ($stmt->num_rows) {
        //echo json_encode("0");
        echo "Unavailable";

        //if unavailable
        // header('Location: /register.html'); 
    }
    else {
        //echo json_encode("1");
        echo "1";
    }

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: Where is the `session_start();`?

Comment: Did you test your web service first.

Comment: check data.trim() == 'Username must be between 3 and 15 characters'

Comment: @Gil I'm not sure waht you mean?

Comment: @saty I copied this code from my old website, so I didn't exactly change anything

Comment: @pshyoulost I meant that if the username isn't saved then maybe the password isn't saved either, and this could be because the session isn't set so the server can't remember anything. And besides, I think it's better to return a JSON object that will hold an error code and error message, so that you'll only check the number instead of comparing a long string that might change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables needed are case sensitive so I needed to change the html from

```
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
```

I was getting an error that says that the value is Null